# Move a tag to another DOM element with Jquery and do CSS3 transition

Tags: jquery, css

My idea is to have an div tag that represents the big logo in the container area of the website and when the scroll goes to certain part that it moves the div to the navbar part but do the CSS3 transition so the moving of the element has a nice effect.

I used jquery to change id of the div and then use appendTo to move it inside the DOM into the navigation. But the transition effect doesn't go off and it just instant moves the div into the navigation. The code Jquery code i'm using is

```
$('#logoTitle').appendTo('.navigation');
$('#logoTitle').attr('id','navLogo');
```

I've added transition: all .5 ease; on both id's in the css file as i would want to move the logo back to position when scroll goes all the way up.

I guess the transition is wrong here as i don't specify any width, or height or top, bot that is transitioning.

I think my aproach to moving the element into the navbar is totaly wrong. I could do this with transition the logo into position: fixed; and then set where it should be placed.

But since I have also a function that hides the navbar on certain events that solution would not work well for me and thats why I went with this approach to the problem. But can't understand how this should be done to trigger animation and then when the animation is done to put the element inside the dom which i would hide later with jquery.

I'm familiar with events on scroll touchmove and that is not the problem for me just this moving and animating.

Answer (score 1):

Most times you need a specific solution for an animating problem like this. But, the easiest way i can think of ist to move the logo with `position: fixed` and `top / left`.

After it moved to the correct location, you have to show the logo in the navigation behind the `position: fixed` logo and then set the `position: fixed` logo to `opacity: 0`.

If it's at the exactly right location, nobody will know that there are in fact two logos.

I hope you understand what i wanted to say.

Comment: I will try this now, one thing i could think of going wrong here is different displaydevice size and how would this affect the animation and positioning of the elements. I'm using <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> hope that will work good, onto it now will report the results.

Comment: Yea. The different display sizes could be little bit of a pain. If you got problems, i'll try to make an example that fits you use case. Just message me.